# want to disable keyboard in ionic app when click on calendar field

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, primeng

I'm using  for my ionic app.
Everything working fine. When I choose  calendar for Date field its displaying keyboard in mobile app.

I want to disable that keyboard when click on calendar input field.

I tried this...

```
    <p-calendar showTime="showTime" id="someThing" placeholder="Start Date & Time" hourFormat="24" [minDate]="minDate"
    [defaultDate]="minDate" (click)="onPickDate()" formControlName="pick_up_datetime" [touchUI]="true" [showIcon]="true" (ionFocus)="keyboard_show()">
```

and ts file like below

```
import {Keyboard} from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

constructor(private keyboard: Keyboard) {
   }
  keyboard_show(){
   this.keyboard.hide();
  }
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, I found working solution,

In `<p-calendar></p-calendar>` there is a default directive called `[readonlyInput]="true"`, add this into p-calendar like this..

```
<p-calendar [showTime]="true"  formControlName="pick_up_datetime" [touchUI]="true" [showIcon]="true" [readonlyInput]="true"></p-calendar>
```

It will work.